# How to access parameter value in controller method from RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc

After saving some data to the db, I pull the newly created userId from the db and I need to send it to the next View.  I am using ReditectToAction to direct it and send the value.  I have verified the value is making it to the redirect but I can't figure out how to grab it, because the model that comes in to AccountSetup is null.  Where am i goig wrong?

method sending the id:

```
            var id = user.UserId;

            var accountModel = new AccountViewModel
            {
                UserId = id
            };

            return RedirectToAction("AccountSetup", "Home", accountModel.UserId);
        }
```

I have verified in debug, that accountModel.userId ha a value.

Method supposed to receive the id:

```
    public ActionResult AccountSetup(AccountViewModel model)
    {
        int id = model.UserId;
```

model is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return RedirectToAction("AccountSetup", "Home", accountModel.UserId);
```

You are not returning the model the action expects but just an id value. Model binder can't bind this value to `AccountViewModel.UserId`, it probably binds it to the `id` parameter in the default route. You are actually expecting a model of type `AccountViewModel` so you should send a `AccountViewModel` instance.

```
return RedirectToAction("AccountSetup", "Home",
                        new AccountViewModel {UserId = accountModel.UserId});
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked great and your explaination makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `TempData` to store anything during the redirect.

```
TempData["MyModel"] = accountModel;
return RedirectToAction("AccountSetup", "Home");
```

And then in the other action:

```
var accountModel = (AccountViewModel)TempData["MyModel"];
int id = accountModel.UserId;
```